# Comparison between an array and array of arrays to insert missing keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to create a comparison between an array of keys and an array of arrays.
The array of array contains the data as the follwing:

```
const data = [
  [["id", 1], ["name", "somethign"], ["age", 20]],
  [["id", 20], ["name", "somethign"]],
  [["id", 9], ["age", 10]]
]
```

An the array with keys, that will always have all the keys I need.

```
const keys = [
  "id",
  "name",
  "age",
  "nothing"
]
```

But as you can see in data array, not always all the keys come in the array, what I was attempting to do was, make a comparison between both arrays an add that key that is missing into the data array (in order) as undefined, for example (final result):

```
const data = [
  [["id", 1], ["name", "somethign"], ["age", 20], ["nothing", undefined]],
  [["id", 20], ["name", "somethign"],["age", undefined] ["nothing", undefined]],
  [["id", 9], ["name", undefined], ["age", 10], ["nothing", undefined]]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method takes these steps:

1. Loops over the `data` in the given order i.e. it will maintain the order of the data.
2. For each row of the data, it loops over the `keys` in the order of keys. So within each row, it will keep the order of the keys and keys will be consistent on top of each other.

I prefer `null` over `undefined` here but you are free to change it to undefined.

```js
const data = [
  [
    ['id', 1],
    ['name', 'somethign'],
    ['age', 20],
  ],
  [
    ['id', 20],
    ['name', 'somethign'],
  ],
  [
    ['id', 9],
    ['age', 10],
  ],
];

const keys = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'nothing'];

const dataWithMissingKeys = data.map(row =>
  keys.map(key => {
    const foundItem = row.find(element => element[0] === key);
    if (foundItem) {
      return foundItem;
    }
    return [key, null];
  })
);

console.log(dataWithMissingKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get a list of existing keys (index 0: `d.map(x => x[0])`)
2. Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the diff between `keys` and `existing` keys
3. Loop over the missing keys
4. Add the desired array to the data array for each missing key

```js
const data = [
    [["id", 1], ["name", "somethign"], ["age", 20]],
    [["id", 20], ["name", "somethign"]],
    [["id", 9], ["age", 10]]
];
const keys = [ "id", "name", "age", "nothing" ];

const fixed = data.map(d => {
    const existing = d.map(x => x[0]);
    const missing = keys.filter(k => !existing.includes(k));

    missing.forEach(m => d.push([ m, undefined ]));
    
    return d;
});

console.log(fixed);
```

Comment: This works, although it doesn't add in order, it is pushing into the last element from the arry

Comment: What do you mean order? Could you explain what needs to be changed?

Comment: There is an example on the question, I think you would need a slice to add into that specific place. In question there is a better example

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach relying on `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`:

- Create an empty base object from your keys,
- Loop over your data,
- For each entry, create an object using `Object.fromEntries`
- Combine that object with the empty base
- Use `Object.entries` to transform back to an array of key-value-pairs

```js
const data = [
  [["id", 1], ["name", "somethign"], ["age", 20]],
  [["id", 20], ["name", "somethign"]],
  [["id", 9], ["age", 10]]
];

const keys = [
  "id",
  "name",
  "age",
  "nothing"
];

const base = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, undefined]));

console.log(
  data.map(d => Object.entries({ ...base, ...Object.fromEntries(d) }))
)
```